# how to pass the selected value from <select> to java code

Tags: java, html, thymeleaf

How to pass a value in java code when choosing an option?

```
<select>
        <option th:each="city:${cities}"
                th:value="${city.value}"
                th:utext="${city.name}"/>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your thymeleaf template you basic need to do 3 things:

1. Need to bind a city object (you need a model named city) to the form element:

> `<form th:action="@{/cities}" method="POST" th:object="${city}">`

2. Add the model to the controller that handles your form view (get controller):

> `model.addAttribute("city", new City());`

3. Add a th:field to your html tag matching your model property field name:

> `<select th:field="*{name}">`

And in your POST controller you need to add your city object as a param/argument and call the service that saves your object into the database:

```
@RestController
public class CityController {

@Autowired 
CityService cityService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/cities", method = RequestMethod.POST) 
public String addCity(City city) { cityService.save(city); }

}
```

Note that the "/cities" value must match with your form action "@{/cities}".

Then in your service class you will have your save method and your cityRepository:

```
@Service 
public class CityService {

@Autowired 
CityRepository cityRepository;

public City save(City city) {   cityRepository.save(city); }

}
```

Finally you need a repository class that extends either from CrudRepository or JpaRepository:

```
@Repository 
public interface CityRepository extends CrudRepository<City, Long> { 

}
```

By extending from CrudRepository you will have access to the save(), findAll(), findById() methods, etc.

Hope that helps!!